# Does the number of texture(s) used effect performance?

Tags: performance, graphics, textures, sfml

I am creating a small 2D game with SFML and met some warnings on the internet saying that I should use as few different textures as possible to achieve maximum performance.

What does the word *use* mean here? Is it just how many textures I have, or *how many my sprites ask for per frame?* Can I use a bunch of textures for the menu (like over 5), or only one while the game runs (the menu textures still exist) and not have performance impacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of textures you use to render a single frame is what can cause performance impact.

If you use only 5 textures, that means that as long as you draw them as efficiently as possible, you only need to switch between textures 5 times per frame.

if you're drawing 10.000 objects, all of which could be drawn using the same single texture, it would be a terrible idea to use 10.000 textures that look exactly the same since you would be switching textures 10.000 times per frame for no reason.

Switching textures isn't free ; it costs times and processor cycles.
So especially in games, we want to do it as little as possible.

Secondly, big textures take up a lot of space.
As long as all your textures fit snugly into memory without any swapping or other tricks, you won't experience much impact from texture size.

But once they become too big, this too starts to have impact.

Comment: To be fair, if you were to implement this all the way from low level GL, you would want to use as little GL calls as possible each frame, since they *all* cost time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that switching from one texture from another **while rendering** is slow, but if I use only a single or two textures for gameplay rendering and a hundred for menu then gameplay won't be slow, right? Because it's bad to **switch** textures and it's not bad to **have** many textures, isn't it?

Comment: As long as they all happily fit in memory, having a bunch of textures won't hurt :)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to find out!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's the texture binding calls (OpenGL `glbindtexture`) that are expensive on performance (if this has not changed with newer OpenGL version). Since SFML runs on top of OpenGL, each Sprite that use a different texture that you need to render will switch the texture to bind the one it needs.

So you could have only 2 textures for your whole project, but switch between the two for each of the 10000 objects and you would still have performance issues. On the other hand, you could have 100 textures (not that this is a good idea) and use the first one for 99% of the rendering and then switch to the 99 other ones and it would be OK for the performance.

I would highly recommend that you batch your assets into bigger images. Like one or two for the game rendering and one or two for the GUI and make sure not to switch too many times. You then use parts (sub rect) of them with `sf::Sprite` which is a lightweight object.

But remember, it's better to get something working before optimizing it. Still, it's never a bad idea to get the information you need to be on the right path from the start.